# composer show dev packages and non dev packages

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there any way to know what packages **will/will not** be autoloaded when using the `--no-dev` flag?

I have inherited some code that uses composer and Im unsure what packages are included in the production build and what are only included in the dev build.

Since doing `composer dump-autoload --no-dev` gives me errors regarding missing classes I suspect that some packages are flagged as dev-only when they should not and I'm trying to track those down.

I havent found anything in the composer docs to help me doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to check which packages are dev-only is to run `composer install` (this will install all dependencies, including dev-only) and then `composer install --no-dev` (this will remove dev-only dependencies). Last command will give you list of removed dependencies - these are packages not available in production builds, you should not rely on them (or move them to `require` section in your `composer.json`).

Example:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 56 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-composer (2.0.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/jquery (3.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/bootstrap (v3.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/inputmask (3.3.11): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/punycode (v1.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/yii2-pjax (2.0.7.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing cebe/markdown (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.17): Loading from cache
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.12): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer (2.0.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.11.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.8.49): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v2.8.49): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.8.49): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.11.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.8.49): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.8.49): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v2.8.49): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v2.8.49): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/browser-kit (v2.8.49): Loading from cache
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (2.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.5.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing codeception/stub (1.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.4.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.2.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/environment (1.3.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.9): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.12): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.2.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.8.36): Loading from cache
  - Installing codeception/phpunit-wrapper (6.0.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing behat/gherkin (v4.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing codeception/base (2.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.6.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing codeception/specify (0.4.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing codeception/verify (0.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap (2.0.9): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-debug (2.0.14): Loading from cache
  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-faker (2.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpspec/php-diff (v1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/typeahead.js (v0.11.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-gii (2.0.8): Loading from cache
Generating autoload files
```

And then list of dev-only dependencies:

```
$ composer install --no-dev
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 44 removals
  - Removing yiisoft/yii2-gii (2.0.8)
  - Removing yiisoft/yii2-faker (2.0.4)
  - Removing yiisoft/yii2-debug (2.0.14)
  - Removing symfony/yaml (v2.8.49)
  - Removing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.11.0)
  - Removing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.11.0)
  - Removing symfony/finder (v2.8.49)
  - Removing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.8.49)
  - Removing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.8.49)
  - Removing symfony/debug (v2.8.49)
  - Removing symfony/css-selector (v2.8.49)
  - Removing symfony/console (v2.8.49)
  - Removing symfony/browser-kit (v2.8.49)
  - Removing sebastian/version (1.0.6)
  - Removing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.5)
  - Removing sebastian/global-state (1.1.1)
  - Removing sebastian/exporter (1.2.2)
  - Removing sebastian/environment (1.3.8)
  - Removing sebastian/diff (1.4.3)
  - Removing sebastian/comparator (1.2.4)
  - Removing ralouphie/getallheaders (2.0.5)
  - Removing psr/log (1.1.0)
  - Removing psr/http-message (1.0.1)
  - Removing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.8)
  - Removing phpunit/phpunit (4.8.36)
  - Removing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.12)
  - Removing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.9)
  - Removing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)
  - Removing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.5)
  - Removing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.2.4)
  - Removing phpspec/prophecy (1.8.0)
  - Removing phpspec/php-diff (v1.1.0)
  - Removing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.5)
  - Removing myclabs/deep-copy (1.6.1)
  - Removing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.5.2)
  - Removing fzaninotto/faker (v1.8.0)
  - Removing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5)
  - Removing codeception/verify (0.3.3)
  - Removing codeception/stub (1.0.4)
  - Removing codeception/specify (0.4.6)
  - Removing codeception/phpunit-wrapper (6.0.10)
  - Removing codeception/base (2.4.1)
  - Removing bower-asset/typeahead.js (v0.11.1)
  - Removing behat/gherkin (v4.6.0)
Generating autoload files
```

---

There is also a [`maglnet/composer-require-checker`](https://github.com/maglnet/ComposerRequireChecker) which may be useful for detecting usage of libraries not listed in `require` section.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered that you can show all root packages using `composer show -s`:

```
name     : roots/bedrock
descrip. : WordPress boilerplate with modern development tools, easier configuration, and an improved folder structure
keywords : bedrock, roots, wordpress, stack, composer, vagrant, wp
versions : * dev-update-and-apply-aq-changes
type     : project
license  : MIT License (MIT) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html#licenseText
homepage : https://roots.io/bedrock/
source   : []  412b5d6779300e49762ed2402d0f87ca50475f2f
dist     : []  412b5d6779300e49762ed2402d0f87ca50475f2f
path     : 
names    : roots/bedrock

support
issues : https://github.com/roots/bedrock/issues
forum : https://discourse.roots.io/category/bedrock

requires
php >=7.0
composer/installers ^1.11
oscarotero/env ^1.2.0
roots/wordpress 5.7.2
roots/wp-password-bcrypt 1.0.0
roots/wp-config 1.0.0
advanced-custom-fields/advanced-custom-fields-pro *
wpackagist-plugin/wordpress-seo ^16.1

requires (dev)
squizlabs/php_codesniffer ^3.0.2
dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer *
wp-coding-standards/wpcs *
wpackagist-plugin/query-monitor ^3.7
roave/security-advisories dev-master
```

And then you can cut out the `requires (dev)` section using `composer show -s | sed -n '/requires (dev)$/,/^$/p'`

```
requires (dev)
squizlabs/php_codesniffer ^3.0.2
dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer *
wp-coding-standards/wpcs *
wpackagist-plugin/query-monitor ^3.7
roave/security-advisories dev-master
```

And then you can get rid of the title using `composer show -s | sed -n '/requires (dev)$/,/^$/p' | grep -v 'requires (dev)'`

```
squizlabs/php_codesniffer ^3.0.2
dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer *
wp-coding-standards/wpcs *
wpackagist-plugin/query-monitor ^3.7
roave/security-advisories dev-master
```

And then you can get rid of the version using `composer show -s | sed -n '/requires (dev)$/,/^$/p' | grep -v 'requires (dev)' | cut -d ' ' -f1`

```
squizlabs/php_codesniffer
dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer
wp-coding-standards/wpcs
wpackagist-plugin/query-monitor
roave/security-advisories
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, any package (and its dependencies) in `require-dev` section of your `composer.json` file will not be autoloaded when you use `composer dump-autoload --no-dev`. Sadly, I don't think there's a command to show those packages together with their dependencies as a single list.

What you can do is try moving each of the packages from `require-dev` section to `require`, reruning `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload --no-dev` to see when your error disappears.